# Codeigniter ajax gives 404 not found

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to use ajax with Codeigniter, but I'm getting a 404 (not found) error.

For ajax I do this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/index.php/ajax/user-sign-up-via-email",
        data: {
            email: email,
            password: password
        }
    });
```

For my Routes.php I have this:

```
$route['ajax/user-sign-up-via-email'] = "UserSignUpViaEmailAjaxController";
```

Am I missing something specific to Codeigniter?

Is it related to first URL parameter being the controller, second parameter being the function to call within the controller?

Comment: Is the 404 coming from your web service, I.E. apache or from codeigniter?

Comment: How can I tell? I just see it in my console returned from the js

Comment: Also does the `UserSignUpViaEmailAjaxController` class exist in `usersignupviaemailajaxcontroller.php` and have an `index()` function? To see which one the 404 is coming from take a look at the response in the network tab of the console and see if the html matches the codeigniter 404 page.

Comment: Can you try this url without ajax, directly from your address bar ?

Comment: @BadWolf thanks I was missing the index()!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comments:

Make sure that the controller you are calling (`UserSignUpViaEmailAjaxController`) has an `index()` function. Since you are remapping the uri directly to a controller without specifying a function it will default to the `index()` function and will 404 if it can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

i do this normally .. u can try this also

```
      url: "<?php echo site_url('customersController/addCustomer'); ?>",
```